# Getting small font size in all text of a table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I want to have small font size in a whole table. I tried with `\small{table code}` and `\begin{\small}{table code} \end{small}`, but it doesn't work. Maybe, I must use a package or any method; please I'm waiting for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use for example `{\scriptsize ... }` around your `\begin{tabular}-\end{tabular}`. this will shrink everything to the given size.

for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
 \caption{Meteorological instruments.}
  \centering\scriptsize
   \begin{tabular}{l l }
\toprule
Measured parameter  &Sensor make and model [serial \#] \\
\midrule
Temperature         &Pt100 in Stevenson screen \\
Barometric pressure &Setra 278 (CS100) [3141007]\\
\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
 \label{tab:sensors}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This example uses the `booktabs` package for the rules.

Comment: Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}.... \end{center}` as this will avoid unnecessary vertical space.

Comment: Also, the pair of braces around `\scriptsize` and the tabular isn't necessary, as the change will be restricted to the `table` environment.

Comment: @Harish Kumar and Torbjørn T., good points. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

```
text

{\small% it is a switch not an environment
... your tabular
}

text
```